# Determine if rounding occurred for a floating-point operation in C/C++

Tags: floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

I am trying to come up with an efficient method to determine when rounding will/did occur for IEEE-754 operations. Unfortunately I am not able to simply check hardware flags. It would have to run on a few different platforms.

One of the approaches I thought of was to perform the operation in different rounding modes to compare the results.

Example for addition:

```
    double result = operand1 + operand2;
    // save rounding mode
    int savedMode = fegetround();
    fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    double upResult = operand1 + operand2;
    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    double downResult = operand1 + operand2;
    // restore rounding mode
    fesetround(savedMode);
    return (result != upResult) || (result != downResult);
```

but this is obviously inefficient because it's having to perform the operation 3 times.

Comment: When you say you are not able to check hardware flags, does that also mean you cannot use the standard C `fegetexceptflag`? If so, I would be surprised if there is a good solution.

Comment: Most often, when the standard C routines are not useful (due to lack of compiler support), a solution is to write inline assembly and customize it for each platform.

Comment: @EricPostpischil By checking hardware flags, I meant explicitly performing the operation and reading the flags in inline assembly. Using `fegetexceptflag` is probably fine, but if I were to use it, are the retrieved flags guaranteed to correspond to the floating-point operation that was just performed?

Comment: The floating-point flags are cumulative, meaning that operations set them, and they remain set until reset. So if you call `fegetexceptflag` and find the inexact flag has been raised, it could have been from the most recent operation or any operation since you previously checked or cleared the flag. (And of course, your C implementation must support `fegetexceptflag`; support for accessing the floating-point environment is optional in C.)

Comment: Reading the flags may be some “expensive,” possibly because it requires instruction synchronization within the processor, so it is generally not something done after each operation. One would usually do a sequence of operations and then check the flags to see if an exception occurred during them, and then divert to alternate processing if one did, with the expectation that such diversion would be rare. For the inexact flag, it is not rare for it to be set in typical floating-point work; it would be rare only in specially designed code.

Answer (score 2):

Your example does not necessarily give the right results with optimization 
levels `-O1` or higher. See this [Godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nGAUgn): 
only one addition `vaddsd` is generated by the compiler.

With optimization 
level `-O0` the assembly looks ok, but that would lead to inefficient code. 
Moreover calling `fegetround` and `fesetround` is relatively expensive, 
compared to the cost of a few floating point operations.

The (self explaining) code below is probably an interesting alternative.
It uses the well-known algorithms 2Sum and 2ProdFMA. On systems without hardware fma, or fma emulation, you can use the 2Prod algorithm instead of 2ProdFMA,
See, for example, *Accurate Floating Point Product and Exponentiation*,
    by Stef Graillat.

```c
/*
gcc -m64 -Wall -O3 -march=haswell round_ex.c -lm
   or with fma emulation on systems without hardware fma support, for example:
gcc -m64 -Wall -O3  -march=nehalem  round_ex.c -lm
*/

#include<math.h>
#include<float.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int add_is_not_exact(double operand1, double operand2){
    double a = operand1;
    double b = operand2;
    double s, t, a_1, b_1, d_a, d_b;
    /* Algorithm 2Sum computes s and t such that a + b = s + t, exactly.         */
    /* Here t is the error of the floating-point addition s = a + b.             */
    /* See, for example, On the robustness of the 2Sum and Fast2Sum algorithms   */
    /* by Boldo, Graillat, and Muller                                            */
    s = a + b;
    a_1 = s - b;
    b_1 = s - a_1;
    d_a = a - a_1;
    d_b = b - b_1;
    t = d_a + d_b;
    return (t!=0.0);
}


int sub_is_not_exact(double operand1, double operand2){
    return add_is_not_exact(operand1, -operand2);
}


int mul_is_not_exact(double operand1, double operand2){
    double a = operand1;
    double b = operand2;
    double s, t;
    /* Algorithm 2ProdFMA computes s and t such that a * b = s + t, exactly.     */
    /* Here t is the error of the floating-point multiplication s = a * b.       */
    /* See, for example, Accurate Floating Point Product and Exponentiation      */
    /* by Graillat                                                               */
    s = a * b;
    t = fma(a, b, -s);
    if (s!=0) return (t!=0.0);       /* No underflow of a*b                                */
    else return (a!=0.0)&&(b!=0.0);  /* Underflow: inexact if s=0, but (a!=0.0)&&(b!=0.0)  */
}


int div_is_not_exact(double operand1, double operand2){
    double a = operand1;
    double b = operand2;
    double s, t;
    s = a / b;
    t = fma(s, b, -a);  /* fma(x,y,z) computes x*y+z with infinite intermediate precision */
    return (t!=0.0);
}


int main(){

    printf("add_is_not_exact(10.0, 1.0) = %i\n", add_is_not_exact(10.0, 1.0));
    printf("sub_is_not_exact(10.0, 1.0) = %i\n", sub_is_not_exact(10.0, 1.0));
    printf("mul_is_not_exact( 2.5, 2.5) = %i\n", mul_is_not_exact( 2.5, 2.5));
    printf("div_is_not_exact(  10, 2.5) = %i\n", div_is_not_exact(  10, 2.5));
    printf("add_is_not_exact(10.0, 0.1) = %i\n", add_is_not_exact(10.0, 0.1));
    printf("sub_is_not_exact(10.0, 0.1) = %i\n", sub_is_not_exact(10.0, 0.1));
    printf("mul_is_not_exact( 2.6, 2.6) = %i\n", mul_is_not_exact( 2.6, 2.6));
    printf("div_is_not_exact(  10, 2.6) = %i\n", div_is_not_exact(  10, 2.6));

    printf("\n0x1.0p-300 = %20e, 0x1.0p-600 = %20e \n", 0x1.0p-300 , 0x1.0p-600 );
    printf("mul_is_not_exact( 0x1.0p-300, 0x1.0p-300) = %i\n", mul_is_not_exact( 0x1.0p-300, 0x1.0p-300));
    printf("mul_is_not_exact( 0x1.0p-600, 0x1.0p-600) = %i\n", mul_is_not_exact( 0x1.0p-600, 0x1.0p-600));

}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./a.out
add_is_not_exact(10.0, 1.0) = 0
sub_is_not_exact(10.0, 1.0) = 0
mul_is_not_exact( 2.5, 2.5) = 0
div_is_not_exact(  10, 2.5) = 0
add_is_not_exact(10.0, 0.1) = 1
sub_is_not_exact(10.0, 0.1) = 1
mul_is_not_exact( 2.6, 2.6) = 1
div_is_not_exact(  10, 2.6) = 1

0x1.0p-300 =         4.909093e-91, 0x1.0p-600 =        2.409920e-181 
mul_is_not_exact( 0x1.0p-300, 0x1.0p-300) = 0
mul_is_not_exact( 0x1.0p-600, 0x1.0p-600) = 1
```

---

As noted in the comments, it is also possible to directly read the 
control and status register:

```c
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int add_is_not_exact_v2(double a, double b)
{    
    fexcept_t excepts;
    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    double c = a+b;
    int tst = fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT);
    return (tst!=0);
}
```

Note, however, that this may not work with compiler optimization level -O1 or higher.
In that case the `addsd` double add instruction is sometimes optimized away completely, 
leading to wrong results.
For example, with gcc 8.2 `gcc -m64 -O1 -march=nehalem`:

```
add_is_not_exact_v2:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, 61
        call    feclearexcept
        mov     edi, 32
        call    fetestexcept
        test    eax, eax
        setne   al
        movzx   eax, al
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

With optimization level `-O0`, with 2 function calls, and with relatively
expansive instructions to modify the control and status register, this is not necessarily the most efficient solution.

Comment: Would the same logic follow if I needed to know if an fma operation is inexact? `s = fma(a, b, c);`  `t = fma(a, b, (c-s));`  Would accuracy be lost when representing the intermediate `c-s` result?

Comment: No, for the exactness of `fma` this doesn't work. For example `fma(1.0, 1.0, 1e-20);` gives an inexact result, but `t=0`. On the other hand, with `a=1.0+2^(-30)` and `b=2^(-60)`, `fma(a,a,-b)` is exact, but `t!=0`. Probably it is possible to test the (in)exactness with a `2prod` and more than one `2sum`s somehow: It should be possible to compute an exact `a*b+c=s+t+u`, and test for `t=u=0`.

Comment: For an error free `[x, y, z] = ThreeFMA(a, b, c)` (`a*b+c=x+y+z`)
see, for example, _Error-free transformations in real and complex floating point arithmetic_, by Graillat and Ménissier-Morain,
and see _Some Functions Computable with a Fused-mac_, by Boldo and Muller.
In that case the `fma` is inexact if `y+z!=0.0`, if no underflow occurs. 
I haven't thought about a solution if underflow (which is rare) occurs.